# How can i translate these bytes to float?

Tags: floating-point, hex, ascii, floating-accuracy, bytestream

\x00 \x16 7G

\x8d \xed 6G

\x1a \x16 7G

\x00 \x16 7G

5E 7G

These is BTCUSDT PRICE data.. so maybe presented like 44xxx.xxx 45xxx.xxx. How can this number make? I can't understand. What i only know is \x is hexnumber and others are maybe ASCII CODES.

Comment: where did you get this data? Is it literal backslash or is it the result when you print using some function? Please provide more information

Comment: I maked these data from python websocket & c_types. I upload these data for IPC via Shared memory. from googling, I understand. If hex is in ASCII, it presented as normal alphabet, else it represented as hex code. THX!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes you have are IEEE-754 encodings of the numbers 46870, 46829.55078125, 46870.1015625, 46870, and 46917.20703125.

To decode them, copy the bytes into a `float` object in little-endian order, then interpret them as that `float` object. Details of how to do this will depend on the programming language used, which the question does not state.

To decode them manually, write out the 32 bits of each four bytes, with the bits of the fourth byte first (in the high-value positions), then the bits of the third byte, then the second, then the first. From those 32 bits, take the first one as a sign bit *s*. Take the next eight as bits for an exponent code *e*. Take the last 23 as bits for a significand code *f*.

Decode the sign bit: Let *S* = (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>.

Decode the exponent bits: Interpret them as an unsigned eight-bit numeral, *e*. Then:

- If *e* is 255 and *f* is zero, then the number represented is +∞ or −∞ according to whether *S* is +1 or −1. The decoding is done, stop.
- If *e* is 255 and *f* is not zero, the data represents a NaN (Not a Number), and *f* contains supplementary information. In typical implementations, if the high bit of *f* is set, the NaN is a quiet, otherwise it is signaling. The decode is done, stop.
- If *e* is zero, let *E* = −126 and let *F* = 0.
- Otherwise, let *E* = *e*−127 and let *F* = 1.

Decode the significand bits: Let *F* = *F* + *f*•2<sup>−23</sup>.

The number represented is *S* • *F* • 2<sup>*E*</sup>.